# Get the key name directly without using next()

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
$foo = array(
    'bar1' => 1,
    'bar2' => 2
);
```

Now i want to get *directly* the name of the second key. How can i do it without using `next()`?

Answer (score 4):

```
$keys=array_keys($foo);
echo $keys[1];
```

If you need only a single key and have PHP 5.4, you can dereference it in one statement:

```
echo array_keys($foo)[1];
```

Comment: EugenRieck thanks, there is not any way to get it usin the name of the index (bar2)?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i would rather love see your comment as answer so that i can upvote it

Comment: @NullPointer If I don't find a dupe I'll answer... Actually I'll just edit this one...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I avoid this, because quite often, **if** you need `array_keys`, you need the output more than once

Comment: @tirengarfio if you already know "bar2", why not just use `$foo['bar2']` ?

Comment: @EugenRieck I completely agree, but OP asks for "directness"

Comment: @tirengarfio Right - what is it you _want_ to know? and what do you _already know_?

Comment: @EugenRieck i already know the name of key, an i want to retrieve it self. Now i'm thinking that is a bit useless because it the key change, i can not retrieve it using its name.. :). In my case the name of the keys are the name of the columns in a table, so I was thinking in the posibility of i18n the name name of those columns and get them directly with a system to i18n behind..do you understand?

Comment: @tirengarfio IIUC, your `$foo` array is a language-dependant translation array. In this case I recommend you use the column name as the key and the value as the I18N value, having the correct version of `$foo`. You could then just use `$friendlyname=$foo['column_name']` without any `array_keys()` trick.

Comment: @EugenRieck i like that (language-dependant translation array).. you are right, but i'm thinking about the translation for the keys (column names)